# ModelMultipleChoiceField validation acting differently depending on widget

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

I have a form with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and it works like a charm.  However, when I set `widget=forms.RadioSelect` the form validation always fails with the error message "Enter a list of values."

As I said, it works perfectly well with the default widget, but not with the radio select widget.  The `POST` request to validate the form is *exactly* the same, everything is *exactly* the same except for the widget, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Why is this?

EDIT: Maybe I should have mentioned it works with `CheckboxSelectMultiple` as well.

EDIT2: It doesn't even seem to matter whether I set `required=False`, it still tells me to "enter a list of values."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I was royally screwing up.  Of course `ModelMultipleChoiceField` doesn't work with `RadioSelect`, because a list of radio buttons means that there can only be one single choice.  The solution is to use `ModelChoiceField`.